# Xamarin Android -TextInputLayout how should I wrap hint to next line of TextInputEditText?

Tags: xamarin.android

Xamarin Android -TextInputLayout how should I wrap hint to next line of TextInputEditText ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LinearLayout` to display a linear direction of elements.

Xaml:

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/textInputEditText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextInputEditText"/>
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**Updated:**

If you want to hint text which is cutting off, you could make a scroll.

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wendy , but the problem is that when TextInputEditText is empty and the hint text is too long, hint text is cutting off, I want to wrap that hint text into the next line. I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: Could you provide more details? If i use the empty `TextInputEditText` and then input a long text, it would enter to the next line.  Check my screenshot: https://imgur.com/n3ur36P

Comment: look at that yellow line this is hint text which is cutting off ,This TextInputEditText is empty and no focus on it